# Why 3 sets of data are being inserted every time when I insert one set data in database using servlet and hibernate in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, servlets

I am using hibernate, spring and servlet jsp in Intellij Idea. I have configured bean for hibernate with prop key as create in applicationContext.xml.

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.himal.hibernate.entity"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

So that every time I run the code table is created.For inserting data , I wrote insert in DAOImplememtation as :

```
@Override
    public void insert(Department department) {
        ///we have to use transaction
        transaction=getSession().beginTransaction();
        session.save(department);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();

    }
```

In the controller class,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class DefaultController {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentDAO departmentDAO;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(){
        departmentDAO.insert(new Department("Science","Chitwan","shyam@xyz.com","999999",90000.0));
        ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView("index");
        modelAndView.addObject("departments",departmentDAO.getAll());
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

When I run the code once, 3 rows of data are inserted into database when I insert one set of data. I cant get where is the problem.

[image]

table id is **autoincremented** and **generated**.

**Entity class [Edited-Added]**

```
package com.himal.hibernate.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * 
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_department")
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "department_name")
    private String departmentName;
    @Column(name = "department_address")
    private String departmentAddress;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "contact_no")
    private String contactNo;
    @Column(name = "total_budget")
    private double totalBudget;

    public Department() {
    }

    public Department(String departmentName, String departmentAddress, String email, String contactNo, double totalBudget) {
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
        this.departmentAddress = departmentAddress;
        this.email = email;
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
        this.totalBudget = totalBudget;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDepartmentName() {
        return departmentName;
    }

    public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
    }

    public String getDepartmentAddress() {
        return departmentAddress;
    }

    public void setDepartmentAddress(String departmentAddress) {
        this.departmentAddress = departmentAddress;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }

    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    public double getTotalBudget() {
        return totalBudget;
    }

    public void setTotalBudget(double totalBudget) {
        this.totalBudget = totalBudget;
    }
}
```

---

**EDITED--ADDED**
In web development network tab under Inspect in chrome

```
General
Request URL:http://localhost:8888/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:[::1]:8888

Response Header
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=CC8867FBF5ACEB167E79AA9077E29F48; Path=/; HttpOnly
Location: http://localhost:8888/departmentEntry
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 22 Sep 2016 15:52:08 GMT

Request Header

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: Idea-f6d59efa=f3dc1041-4d4a-41fe-97cc-b6fc42f0938b; JSESSIONID=6A9C3DE20395F06A58ED264CB686C6D4
```

Comment: Could you add the controller code that calls the `insert` method ?

Comment: I have already added the controller code that calls the insert method above in **in 3rd block of code**

Comment: Could you please provide the code of your entity

Comment: Ankit: I added the entity class

Comment: Sorry, i missed it. When you say : 'When I run the code once', do you mean you open a browser on '/' ? Could the generated html (by the view 'index') trigger more http request on '/' (like ajax calls) ? Using webDevelopper extension -- network tab--, you can see all the http requests going out of the browser.

Comment: I have made auto redirected to hello.jsp. When I hit loclahost:8888, it displays hello page.BTW, this time  2 sets of data were inserted. Some hours ago when I run Tomcat server , 4 sets of data were inserted in database.

I have added my webdeveloper network tab hsitory

Comment: It's most likely that JavaScript is called multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with your application or default mapping ("/"). you need to check what requests were made to the server by the browser.

I guess, your index method is called thrice. To check this add some logs or print some data to check whether it is called thrice.
If it is so, then there might be some background process(filter, load-on-startup etc.) running in your application.
Use **HttpRequester extension** for firefox  and create a **new request** using that extension.
OR
The insert method is called thrice. Check the Call-hierarchy of insert method, How many times it is called.

Comment: If I change to other, it will work.. I am curious what's the issue if there is default mapping. only one set of data stored on default mapping if I take data from form.

Comment: I removed load on start up..Still same. but sometime 2 sets sometimes 3 sets sometime 4 sets of data inserted

Comment: have you added some logs in the insert method? just to test whether its called thrice. System.out.println("Inside insert"); Also check the history of URL's in the HttpRequester extension.

Comment: 2 logs inside insert method. Somehours ago, there were 3 .

Comment: When I send request in  Postman for Httprequester in Chrome, then only one set of data is inserted.When I send request in Microsoft Edge, only one set of data inserted but request is send using Chrome, this time 2 sets of data inserted.

Comment: Ok, so no issues with app. Its the browser issue, may be some advertisement virus etc. use adblock plus extension or re-install the chrome browser.